# Selective sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, package-management, updates

If I run:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

It upgrades all the packages on my system, including LibreOffice, Chrome & Firefox, which for me is undesirable.

How can I tell Ubuntu to only install system patches, whilst allowing me to manually upgrade my applications?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 x64

Comment: What do you call "system patches"? You can select packages to upgrade. You can also set selected packages to be held too.

Comment: @Pilot6 - Security updates, updates to system libraries like the MP4 codecs... Basically everything it normally upgrades except for user applications.

Comment: That is not a good idea. User applications may depend on specific versions of other packages. For your purpose I would suggest to hold some packages you do not want to upgrade. But I would not recommend doing it though.

Comment: @JonasCz - I don't think so because I don't use Synaptic

Comment: I think the answers, esp. regarding "holding" also apply if you don't use synaptic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try the following command

```
sudo apt-mark hold <package_name>
```

This will prevent it from being updated when running the usual upgrade command (`sudo apt-get upgrade`). It should also work in your case. To undo this you can run

```
sudo apt-mark unhold <package_name>
```

It probably isnt a good idea to prevent packages from updating. New updates could include security fixes or bug fixes. Preventing these upgrades could be harmful for you system. Also as Pilot6 said in the comments, not upgrading the packages could prevent the applications from working altogethor. so be cautious when you decide to hold packages from upgrades.

Comment: Thanks. I realize I didn't put this in the initial question, but any way to do that through Software Center?

Comment: Not really sure, I stopped using software center and stuck to `apt-get` a long time back, since its a lot faster (atleast on my laptop)

Comment: @AndroidDev Software Center is buggy and not really maintained, so `apt` on the command line is better

Comment: In fact the software center was replaced in 16.04

Comment: Synaptic, which is a more sophisticated package-manager would offer this. It offers than also a list of packages beeing held. You cannot even seletively install a package from "proposed" with a software-center to confirm it fixes a bug. that's my impression. But Synaptic is co-installable. So far I have not yet met a person who has all counter-parts of given options for command-line at hand.